# Secure Windows 10 Machine

Tags: windows, windows-10

Two days ago a shady pop up was left running in the background for hours, when I returned to my computer, I had some error in the pop up window that network connection was lost from sleep.

Today I woke up in the middle of the night to the sound of my computer which was asleep to a windows bloop.  I noticed my computer had woken up from it's slumber.

Windows 10 constantly has High Process, Disk and Wifi Usage for service which I do not need running.

What is the best way to assure my computer is clean?

Download a copy of windows, from a secure machine as well as the bios for my computer,

Restart My computer, Flash the bios, Reformat my machine,  and the only access my old files from a VM?

Is there anything other steps I should take as a precaution, like Flash my video card, etc.  I know this question may sound broad, but I am trying to understand what the steps are for fully securing a computer?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would do is run Wireshark and log some traffic to analyze later. Then you should boot from another system and virus-scan, malware scan, etc. the bejeezus out of it with your favorite scanners. You will lose at least a day or two on machine time, but at least you won't be infected anymore and may have logged the attackers IP.